# How to output an operation sample request like SOAPUI?

Tags: python, xml, wsdl, soapui, zeep

Hi I would like to get a sample request like how SOAPUI does it but i would like to use Python so i can make extra string manipulations.

The wsdl is: https://wd2-impl-services1.workday.com/ccx/service/workdayproserv_dpt2/Resource_Management/v41.0?wsdl

Operation is: Adjust_Asset_Cost

The sample request from SOAPUI:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bsvc="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <bsvc:Workday_Common_Header>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <bsvc:Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response>?</bsvc:Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response>
      </bsvc:Workday_Common_Header>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bsvc:Adjust_Asset_Cost_Request bsvc:version="?">
         <bsvc:Business_Asset_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="?">
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="?">?</bsvc:ID>
         </bsvc:Business_Asset_Reference>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <bsvc:Business_Process_Parameters>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <bsvc:Auto_Complete>?</bsvc:Auto_Complete>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <bsvc:Comment_Data>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <bsvc:Comment>?</bsvc:Comment>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <bsvc:Worker_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="?">
                  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                  <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="?">?</bsvc:ID>
               </bsvc:Worker_Reference>
            </bsvc:Comment_Data>
         </bsvc:Business_Process_Parameters>
         <bsvc:Business_Asset_Cost_Adjustment_Data>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <bsvc:Post_Acquisition_Adjustment>?</bsvc:Post_Acquisition_Adjustment>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <bsvc:Transaction_Effective_Date>?</bsvc:Transaction_Effective_Date>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <bsvc:Currency_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="?">
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="?">?</bsvc:ID>
            </bsvc:Currency_Reference>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <bsvc:Adjustment_Amount>?</bsvc:Adjustment_Amount>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <bsvc:Adjustment_Quantity>?</bsvc:Adjustment_Quantity>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <bsvc:Adjustment_Residual_Value>?</bsvc:Adjustment_Residual_Value>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <bsvc:Accounting_Date>?</bsvc:Accounting_Date>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <bsvc:Restricted_to_Books_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="?">
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="?">?</bsvc:ID>
            </bsvc:Restricted_to_Books_Reference>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <bsvc:Adjustment_Reason_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="?">
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="?">?</bsvc:ID>
            </bsvc:Adjustment_Reason_Reference>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <bsvc:Supplier_Invoice_Line_Reference_ID>?</bsvc:Supplier_Invoice_Line_Reference_ID>
         </bsvc:Business_Asset_Cost_Adjustment_Data>
      </bsvc:Adjust_Asset_Cost_Request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

It does not required any user credential or tokens.
I have tried to use zeep but getting service not found error, and i have confirmed the operation service exists:

```py
from zeep import Client
from zeep.wsse.username import UsernameToken

# Define the WSDL URL and operation name
wsdl_url = "https://wd2-impl-services1.workday.com/ccx/service/workdayproserv_dpt2/Resource_Management/v41.0?wsdl"
operation_name = "Adjust_Asset_Cost"

# Create a Zeep client using the WSDL URL
client = Client(wsdl=wsdl_url)

# Print the sample request for the specified operation
operation = client.bind(operation_name, "adjustAssetCost")
sample_request = client.create_message(operation_name, _soapheaders=[UsernameToken("", "")])

print(sample_request)
```

Comment: it said service not found, and i tried suds, it will said failed on SSL

Comment: I'm getting a credential error when trying without credentials.

Comment: SOAPUI to display the sample request does not need a credential, i wonder if somehow we can do the same?

Comment: The link you provided is the WSDL, not a request.  It is a schema and not an actual request.  If the server requires a credential you need to send a credential.  If you are an admin for the server than you can change the server.